# Disconnected set definition

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand why is the closure relevant in the following definition. In other words, why wouldn't the definition omit the closure of $A$ and the closure of $B$ ?

We say $A,B$ disconnect a set $X\subset\mathbb{R}$, if $\overline{A}\cap B = A\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$, and $X = A\cup B$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every set $S$ with at least two elements can be decomposed into two non-empty disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ whose union equals the entire set. By requiring that each set's closure doesn't intersect the other we mean that no element of $A$ is a limit point of $B$ and vice versa. This is critical for disconnecting the set because although every element of $S$ is in either $A$ or $B$, there is a gap between $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple example consider the subsets of the reals on intervals $(0,1)$ and $[1,2)$. It's not hard to see that their union is connected since it's the interval $(0,2)$. If we had instead chosen $(1,2)$ instead of $[1,2)$ however then the sets can be covered with the open sets $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ so they are disconnected. Essentially the closure captures the possibility that they could share a common boundary and one of the sets can contain that boundary which would connect them after you take the union.